# Implicit identity of group unit?

Tags: logic, education

In the following:

```
Let G be a group such that a^2=e for every a in G.
```

it is obvious that here `e` refers to the unit of the group `G`.

But if I wrote

```
Let G be a group such that a^2=x for every a in G.
```

the identity of `x` wouldn't be so obvious.

Even worse if an `e` is already restricted as the Euler number, e.g. if we are talking about groups made of real functions.

Could one give me a short reasoning why `e` refers to the unit in the first but `x` does not in the second example?

Comment: I once was told a story (which might well be apocryphal) about a guy who submitted an otherwise sound and intersting paper in group theory - only, he/she was referring to the identity element as *Alexander*. The referee complained that it was non-standard - but that could be accepted - but it was definitely too long. The author changed it to *Alex*. It occured to me that this is an extension of both the notations you mention.

Comment: Yes it's just notational convention, but such ambiguity ought to be avoided where possible, unless you really have no space in the margin...

Answer (score 1):

In the case at hand, we can determine that $e$ (and, in the second example, $x$) must be the identity because it's the square of *every* element and therefore in particular the square of the identity, which is of course just the identity.

But in general, the reason we understand $e$ (but not $x$) as being the identity is because enough authors have used this notation and we've gotten used to it. If another $e$ is under discussion also, then using $e$ for two different things would be a mistake.

Comment: so would you say that there is a global `e` object which assumes properties based on and limited to the the context it appears, but there is no such `x` object?

Comment: No, I wouldn't think of this in terms of a single object whose properties vary; the properties vary so much that it seems better to think of a single symbol denoting numerous objects.  (In addition to "identity of group" and "base of natural logarithms", there's the fundamental unit of electric charge, and there are undoubtedly others that I'm not thinking of right now.)